# Having problems getting a Powershell Timeout working

Tags: powershell

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here, it's killing me...
I want the loop to stop if it's been over a minute or SomeFile.txt shows up. Thanks

```
$EndTimer = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(1)
while (((Get-Date) -le $EndTimer) -or (!(Test-Path "$LocPath\SomeFile.txt"))) {2..1 | ForEach {Start-Sleep -Seconds $_ ;"Processing..."}}
```

Comment: What isn't working for you? Does it stop too soon? Never? Not if the file is there? Do you get errors?

Comment: The loop only stops when the "$LocPath\SomeFile.txt" shows up. I want it to stop when a minute is up OR the file shows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `-and` instead of `-or` in your condition.

You want the loop to continue "while" the timer isn't expired and the file doesn't exist.

Comment: I want the loop to continue "while" the timer isn't expired OR the file doesn't exist.

Comment: As soon as one of the conditions is false (it's past the time) or the file starts existing, you want it to exit.  You don't need both to be false (which would use an -or).